# How to add lines above and below a certain line in Powershell based on regex pattern?

Tags: powershell, filesystems, shell-script, automation, powershell-5.0

```
03,201779,,01354,73923309,,,TEST2,7962753,,,0343,5087632,,/#end of line
04,399,777873,,,,text234,,,,/ 
33,TEST1,,,0343,,93493,,,343,,,,TEST3,,,,,,/
37,TEST37,text
49,24605597,6,343,343,343,,,3434,,,/
```

There are 50 thousand sections that start from 03 record and end at 49 record in my .txt file.

```
I want to add a record say:- "02, 33, TEST02,,,,022,,,99/  ABOVE all 03 records.
I want to add a record say:- "50, 3434, TEST50,,,034,,,343/  BELOW all 49 records.
```

This code is not working - please help me - this is very very important .. i need to do this for a urgent task.

```
$FileName = "C:\testdata\file.txt"
$Pattern = "[03,]"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file = Get-Content $FileName
$insert = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $file.count; $i++) {
  if ($file[$i] -match $pattern) {
    $insert += $i-1 #Record the position of the line before this one
  }
}

#Now loop the recorded array positions and insert the new text
$insert | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { $file.insert($_,"02, 33, TEST02,,,,022,,,99/") }

Set-Content $FileName $file
```

Comment: Use `$Pattern = "^03,"` so the caret for the beginning of the line, remove the `$insert = @()` and then `$file.Insert($i, "02, 33, TEST02,,,,022,,,99/"); $i++;` in the `If()` condition within the `{ }` curly brackets. Same on the patter for `"^49,"` but then use only `file.Insert($i + 1, "50, 3434, TEST50,,,034,,,343/")` within its `If()` action within the curly bracket and then finish the end with `Set-Content $FileName $file` and then check the file. One does line before and the other does line after using the [insert](https://ss64.com/ps/insert.html) method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Insert() method makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code :

```
$fileName = "C:\testdata\file.txt"
(Get-Content $fileName) |
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_.StartsWith("03,")) {
            Write-Output "02, 33, TEST02,,,,022,,,99/"
        }
        Write-Output $_                 # send the current line to output
        if ($_.StartsWith("49,")) {
            Write-Output "50, 3434, TEST50,,,034,,,343/"
        }
    }
```